# QSpinBox signal for arrow buttons

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, signals-slots, qspinbox

I know this question has been asked in similar ways, but I'm getting lost in the vast world of the many signals I can choose from when using a `QSpinBox` (or `QDoubleSpinBox`). I want to connect my function to the `editingFinished` signal (fine, it works perfectly), but this will not also connect to the arrow-buttons - so I need signals for those as well. I don't want to call my function every time `valueChanged` is emitted - only when editing is finished, or when the arrows are used.

Comment: your explanation is confuse, what do you want?

Comment: Do you want a signal that informs you if you press the button up or down?

Comment: Exactly that, yes. Which one does not matter, just the signal that one of them has been pressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to reimplement the [stepBy method](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qabstractspinbox.html#stepBy) and emit a custom signal. The main advantage of this approach is that it will handle changes made using the up/down keys, as well as the arrow buttons. Here is a basic demo:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class SpinBox(QtGui.QSpinBox):
    stepChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def stepBy(self, step):
        value = self.value()
        super(SpinBox, self).stepBy(step)
        if self.value() != value:
            self.stepChanged.emit()

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.spin = SpinBox()
        self.spin.editingFinished.connect(self.handleSpinChanged)
        self.spin.stepChanged.connect(self.handleSpinChanged)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.spin)

    def handleSpinChanged(self):
        print(self.spin.value())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 150, 50)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Perfect! Thanks a lot :)